# Android Firebase Dynamic-Link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I created Dynamic Link Using Firebase and if I share share it via Gmail or Message,
it's detecting my app and working properly, but if I share my link via Skype it is unable to detect my app it's directly redirecting to playstore.

Comment: Did you add support for Android app links, e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#app_links

Comment: @IanBarber  i'am handling app Link also still it's not detecting my app from Skype

Comment: Possibly skype is not triggering an intent, they're manually opening a web view themselves. If that's the case, there's not a lot you can do - if they choose to display it in a webview, the system will never get a chance to intervene.